# Function uses intellisense to accept multiple Enums

Tags: vba, excel, enums, intellisense, user-defined-functions

I have an Enum declared in VBA

```
Enum myEnum
    valA = 3
    valB = 17
    valC = 20
End Enum
```

I would like a function which accepts any combination of the values specified by this Enum, and employs Intellisense when you enter them. I.e., it prompts me with the possible values I can input.

Now if I could choose the values in my Enum to be powers of two, then I would probably do as Chip Pearson suggests in [his section on Composite Values](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx), namely

```
Function myFunction(val As myEnum)
    '...
End Function
```

Usage

```
Debug.Print myFunction(valA + valB) 'with intellisense
```

However my Enums do not follow that pattern, so there's no way I can think of to discern whether `valA + valB` was input, or `valC` for example. Therefore I'm wondering:

**Is there any way to pass an array/undetermined number of variables to a function, whilst still using Intellisense to suggest possible values?**

Comment: Nope.  ParamArray allows arbitrary variable arguments but its a variant type so no intellisense.  A bitmask (composite) it the most elegant way to do this if at all possible.  The only other alternatives require extra setup code, passing a strongly typed array for example.

Comment: Why aren't you using powers of 2 *if you KNOW that this is how it's done*, that it works *and* keeps IntelliSense?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Unfortunately I couldn't pick the values in the Enum, they are a selection of *magic numbers* (which microsoft came up with) that I wanted to enumerate.

Comment: Use a power-of-two enum as lookup values (in a dictionary/select case utility function) for the true values?

Comment: Microsoft came up with them? If the values aren't powers of 2, then the enum wasn't *meant* to be used as a composite value. What's the actual enum?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Sorry, poorly written. I'm using the [GetDetailsOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870(v=vs.85).aspx) shell function, which requires an "*magic number*" integer argument, corresponding to various return values. I have created an Enum to represent a subset of these integers, and now would like to create a function which takes a group of inputs from that enumerated subset and outputs the corresponding return values.

Comment: Seems you're making your life much more complicated than it needs to be by using enums, when combining constants and arrays (or collections) would suffice.

Comment: Enums are not the thing then but just for fun here is a horrible way to do it: `valA = (2 * &H10000) + (&HFFFF& And 7)` (where 2 doubles for `valB` and so on) which can be tested with `if val And (myEnum.valA / &H10000) And &HFFFF& Then //valA is set`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Flag enums use powers of 2 exactly for that.

```
Public Enum Foo
    V1 = 2 ^ 0
    V2 = 2 ^ 1
    V3 = 2 ^ 2
    V4 = 2 ^ 3
    V5 = 2 ^ 4
    '...
End Enum
```

The reason for this is that they allow you to use bitwise logic to determine which bits are "on", given a composite value, for example `5` which can only be `4 + 1`:

```
Power    2^5  2^4 2^3  2^2  2^1  2^0 
Value     32   16   8    4    2    1
Bit        0    0   0    1    0    1
```

As was [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45696049/function-uses-intellisense-to-accept-multiple-enums#comment78350660_45696049), another way could be to use a `ParamArray` parameter, but that can only ever be `Variant`, and can only ever be passed `ByRef`, which not only means you lose IntelliSense, you also lose the semantic safety of passing parameter values `ByVal` (well, your code *implicitly* passes it `ByRef` anyway).

So either you come up with a way to "map" individual "magic underlying values" enum members to flag enum members (with powers of 2), or you forfeit IntelliSense.

```
Private Function GetFlag(ByVal value As MyEnum) As MyFlagEnum
    Static converter As Scripting.Dictionary
    If converter Is Nothing Then
        Set converter = New Scripting.Dictionary
        With converter
            .Add MyEnum.valA, MyFlagEnum.ValueA
            .Add MyEnum.valB, MyFlagEnum.ValueB
            .Add MyEnum.valC, MyFlagEnum.ValueC
            .Add MyEnum.valD, MyFlagEnum.ValueD
            .Add MyEnum.valE, MyFlagEnum.ValueE
        End With
    End If
    GetFlag = converter(value)
End Function
```

And then you can combine them *after pulling the mapped value*:

```
Debug.Print MyFunction(GetFlag(valA) + GetFlag(valB)) ' intellisense everywhere!
```

Where `MyFunction` takes a `MyFlagEnum` value.

If the underlying values have a specific meaning and they're carved in stone and `MyFunction` needs to use them, you need another function to "unwrap" individual FlagEnum values into individual "MyEnum" values:

```
Private Function GetFromFlag(ByVal value As MyFlagEnum) As MyEnum
    Static converter As Scripting.Dictionary
    If converter Is Nothing Then
        Set converter = New Scripting.Dictionary
        With converter
            .Add MyFlagEnum.ValueA, MyFlagEnum.valA
            .Add MyFlagEnum.ValueB, MyFlagEnum.valB
            .Add MyFlagEnum.ValueC, MyFlagEnum.valC
            .Add MyFlagEnum.ValueD, MyFlagEnum.valD
            .Add MyFlagEnum.ValueE, MyFlagEnum.valE
        End With
    End If
    GetFromFlag = converter(value)
End Function
```

And then again, use that function *with the individual **not combined** values*. So the first thing `MyFunction` needs to do is to determine what individual flags are "on", and then `GetFromFlag` each one of them to get the individual non-flag enum values.

This should be useful:

```
Private Function HasFlag(ByVal composite As Long, ByVal flag As Long) As Boolean
    HasFlag = (composite And flag) = flag
End Function
```